# CSS postion align

Tags: html, css, frontend

I don't understand why when I change `position` to `relative`, the "facebook and Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life" lies at the top of the page. I've just started learning css for three days. Thanks!!!!

This is the `html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="henry.css">
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="h1">
        <h1 class="h">facebook</h1>
        <p class="pr">Facebook helps you connect and share with the people in your life.</p>
        </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

`css` file

```
.h1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Positioning is complicated stuff that's rarely useful. I wouldn't go near it three days into CSS. Better to spend your time on the basics, and then Flexbox and Grid before thinking about Positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need align elements, first try `flexbox`(remenber to add `flex` on the parent elements what you want align): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

After some struggle with flexbox, try to align with `grid`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

---

**FLEXBOX X GRID:**

**Flexbox**: unidirection align, to aligning center vertical all elements in a list of posts

**Grid**: bidirectional align, generaly use to structure your page the places they will be "header, footer, menu, body..." and inside FOOTER you can use flexbox and is very common

(in first view is hard, but one day make sense to you :D)

---

Theses properties (flexbox, grid..) is a fluid structure where one HTML element interfere/support to another, try in "inspect elements"(in browser) and play to delete some HTML Nodes like `DIV`s, `SPAN`s... and see how to behave  elements in screen.

Inside these elements add a `div` (equal you create) with position absolute. and in inspect element (in browser) and delete these element. You will understand the element position "put it out" to structure where element interfere to anoter.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` positions an element relative to its first not static ancestor element. In this case, the `div` with class name "h1", the one that wraps those two sentences, has as ancestor the `<body>` element: this makes your div go at the top.

Little tip: avoid giving keywords as class names, it can be confusing.
I'd switch from  to  or

Answer (score -1):

`position: relative` cannot be aligned in the same way as absolutely positioned elements can be using `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right`. Using these will instead shift their position based off of where they should be in relation to other elements.

Since there are no other elements in the DOM, the element will sit at the top.

---

`position: absolute`, which is what I assume you were using before ignores all other elements.

If you would like to give this div an offset, use the `margin` CSS property. 
(`margin-top`, `margin-left`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-right`).

However, you cannot give a relatively positioned element a top offset without using a display, such as `display: flex` or `display: grid`

Sorry for my rushed first answer, I hope this clears things up.

Comment: This answer is very incorrect. Position relative can be aligned relative to other elements with top, bottom etc. and if there is no positioned ancestor it will work the same as fixed iirc.

Comment: @ZachJensz ah, my bad. I meant to say that it will work differently on a relatively positioned element. I will edit my answer now